# Change GridView size based on window size (UWP)

Tags: c#, gridview, width, win-universal-app

I would like for the gridview width size to change as the window size is altered. I have tried to do this with the following in xaml and c#. Whilst this does work as the page is loaded with a different window size, it doesn't change dynamically as the window size is changed.

I have tried this with adaptive triggers however I can't get the grid width to change size.

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="GridViewWith">
                <VisualState x:Name="Big">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="gridView.Width" Value="500"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And the grid itself:

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Margin="0,40,0,0">
            <GridView x:Name="gridView" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None" ItemClick="gridView_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="601">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>                             
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" xml:space="preserve" Text="Size: " />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="{Binding Size}"  />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Why do you change the size in code behind? Why not using XAML Syntax for that?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn958435.aspx

Comment: Are you wanting to change the `GridView` itself or the size of the items?

Comment: I wanted to change the size of the gridview, but I have since figured out that taking out the scroll viewer will enable gridview to resize so it is working somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Adaptive Triggers yo chance the sizeof your grid automatically when the screen size changed
it's very easy to use.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week03aug15/designing-with-adaptive-triggers-for-windows-10/